# Why cant I inherit the parent's width with my table?

Tags: html, css

For some reason i cant inherit the parent's width with a table element

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bu3zV/)

CSS:

```
body {
    margin:0;
}
#main_wrap {
    max-width:1000px;
    height:400px;
    border-style:groove;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
}
#menu {
    width:inherit;
    height:50px;
    border-style:double;
}
#menu table {
    width:inherit;
    height:inherit;
    background-color:rgba(255, 0, 4, 1.00);
}
#menu2 {
    width:inherit;
    height:50px;
    border-style:double;
}
#test {
    width:inherit;
    height:inherit;
    background-color:rgba(255, 0, 4, 1.00);
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="main_wrap">
    <div id="menu">
        <table>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>a</td>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2">
        <div id="test"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The inheritance works when I inherit to a div element in the same circumstance.
Cant a table inherit from an element which properties are already inherited?
Why is it working with div, but not with the table?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the issue occurs because the table is not a block element.  A table's width cannot be inherited and is determined solely on set width or the width of content.  Adding a width of 100% will get you the desired results.

```
width: 100%;
```

Answer (score 1):

YOu shoud add `width: 100%` to the main container.

```
#main_wrap {
    width: 100%;
    max-width:1000px;
    ....
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robcabrera/D262Z/

Answer (score 1):

Table and Div do not have the same behaviour.
If you add css to your table : display: block; you'll see it has the same behaviour. But you will lose the table behaviour though.
That explains the difference between the 2 exemples.